# How to print the third instance of an attribute using Cheerio JS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

There is 3 instances of 'authenticity_token' in this html:

```
<form class="edit_checkout" action="/942252/checkouts/624527ae778897e534d917b52af2eb28" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="5vK3h2ocwaKm0hZ+AH3HAtnffe9l7hQHIMDfrMPusFhxtSV6IbLBfWOnBboOBysF7NyDPQ7GNxdfcWUPOk5WSQ==" />

<form class="edit_checkout" action="/942252/checkouts/624527ae778897e534d917b52af2eb28" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Fkw7j/Wv0Xxhna1aWNh8FsZhNnXz4zu0vFuTV0q9WJ6BC6lyvgHRo6Tovp5WopAR82LIp5jLGKTD6in0sx2+jw==" />

<form class="edit_checkout" data-payment-form="" action="/942252/checkouts/624527ae778897e534d917b52af2eb28" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Bs1PNacx4rK5TJcl+VDO+RXnR69DixOH+osJ/yxuQQeRit3I7J/ibXw5hOH3KiL+IOS5fSijMJeFOrNc1c6nFg==" />
```

The actual token (the value I want) is the value attribute and in this case I want the 3rd instance of 'authenticity_token'.

All 3 instances start with `<form class="edit_checkout"` but the third is followed by `data-payment-form=""` instead of `action="/` . so I know the one I want is the one that includes `data-payment-form`

I tried using this code in Cheerio:

```
$('form.edit_checkout input['name="authenticity_token"']')
```

But that returns the first auth token on the first line and I need the auth token on the third line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let input = $('[name="authenticity_token"]')[2]
```

Then to get the value:

```
let value = $(input).attr('value')
```

Comment: for let value do u mean:
`let value = $(input).attr('value')` because the token is the value of the element

Comment: This returned undefined

Comment: My code that returned undefined: `token = $('[name="authenticity_token"]')[2]
      orderAuth = $(token).attr('value')`

Comment: Ok, that's the same thing you just renamed the variables.